# How To Apply Indexing this Query

Tags: php, mysql, indexing

```
SELECT  user_id,username,full_name,display_name,profile_pic,email,
        fb_id,image1,image2,image3,image4,image5,default_pic,
        street_address,locality,country,state,is_verified,is_online,
        city,image6,image7,image8,image9,image10,last_login,
        IFNULL( (
                SELECT  STATUS
                    FROM  vidioo_contacts
                    WHERE  (contact_id = '55000'
                              AND  user_id = vu.user_id
                          )
                      OR  (contact_id = vu.user_id
                              AND  user_id = '55000')),0) AS STATUS,
        (3959 * ACOS( COS(RADIANS(0)) * COS(RADIANS(latitude)) * 
           COS(RADIANS(longitude) - RADIANS(0)) + SIN(RADIANS(0)) *
           SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))
           ) AS distance
    FROM  vidioo_users vu
    WHERE  user_id != '55000'
      AND  gender LIKE 
        ( SELECT  CASE WHEN show_me = 'everyone'
                     THEN '%'
                     ELSE IF(LENGTH(show_me) < 1, '%', show_me)
                  END
            FROM  vidioo_users
            WHERE  user_id = '55000'
            LIMIT  1 
        )
      AND  IFNULL(vu.is_deleted,0) != 55000
      AND  vu.user_id NOT IN (
        SELECT  DISTINCT contact_id
            FROM  vidioo_blocked_users
            WHERE  bloked_by_user = 55000
                          )
      AND  DATEDIFF(NOW(),last_login) < 7
    ORDER BY  last_login DESC
    LIMIT  0,20
```

I wish to apply indexing to this query.

Comment: First, normalise your design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the table has a multiple-column index then mysql uses leftmost prefix of the index. For example you have following select queries -

`SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1;
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1 AND col2=val2;

SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col2=val2;
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col2=val2 AND col3=val3;`

If an index exists on (col1, col2, col3), only the first two queries use the index. The third and fourth queries do involve indexed columns, but (col2) and (col2, col3) are not leftmost prefixes of (col1, col2, col3).

In your case you must have to create  3 indexes as

1. Index_1(user_id, gender, last_login)
2. Index_2(user_id)
3. Index_3(bloked_by_user)

**NOTE:-** Too many indexing slow down INSERT query processing.
For more details [Click here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding indexes on these four table columns, It should help:

```
contact_id,
user_id,
is_deleted,
last_login.
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other suggestions, change `AND  DATEDIFF(NOW(),last_login) < 7` to

```
last_login > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

What you have hides the column `last_login` inside a function (`DATEDIFF`), making it unusable with indexing.  Then, also, add

```
INDEX(last_login)
```

(It may not help, but it may.)

Also, change

```
AND  vu.user_id NOT IN (
    SELECT  DISTINCT contact_id
        FROM  vidioo_blocked_users
        WHERE  bloked_by_user = 55000
                      )
```

to

```
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM vidioo_blocked_users
        WHERE  bloked_by_user = 55000
          AND  contact_id = vu.user_id )
```

Together with

```
INDEX(bloked_by_user, contact_id) -- in either order
```